# Android ACTION_UP and ACTION_MOVE doesn't work in live wallpaper AndEngine

Tags: android, touch, andengine, live-wallpaper

I'm creating live wallpaper based on AndEngine Live Wallpaper Extension.
In function onCreateScene() I set touch event to my scene. Here is code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback) {
  mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

  parallaxBackground = new ParallaxBackground(0, 0, 0);
  parallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(1.0f, mySprite));
  mCurrentScene.setBackground(parallaxBackground);

  mCurrentScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);

  pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(mCurrentScene);
}
```

after that I creat onSceneTouchEvent() function:

```
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene scene, TouchEvent event) {
switch(event.getAction()){
    case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                    
        Log.i("Logged TouchEvent DOWN", ""+event.getAction());
        break;
    case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        Log.i("Logged TouchEvent MOVE", ""+event.getAction());
        break;
    case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:
        Log.i("Logged TouchEvent UP", ""+event.getAction());
        break;
}
return true;        
}
```

All is right in this code?
Ok. I'm running it on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S III mini)..., when I touch on screen at first time, in the log is writing:

```
AndEngine                     org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 0 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
Logged TouchEvent DOWN        0
```

when I touch on screen at second time and etc, in the log is writing:

```
Logged TouchEvent DOWN        0
Logged TouchEvent DOWN        0
Logged TouchEvent DOWN        0
Logged TouchEvent DOWN        0
.....
```

...only ACTION_DOWN is detected! 
ACTION_UP and ACTION_MOVE doesn't work!

Maybe all touch events doesn't available in AndEngine Live Wallpaper Extension? Who know?
How to solve this problem?

Comment: You're supposed to post an answer...

Answer (score 1):

I solve it reimplementing the BaseWallpaperGLEngine class.

In your LiveWallpaperService insert this code:

```
@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    return new LiveWallpaperEngine(this);
}

public class LiveWallpaperEngine extends BaseWallpaperGLEngine {

    public LiveWallpaperEngine(IRendererListener pRendererListener) {
        super(pRendererListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mEngine.onTouch(null, MotionEvent.obtain(event));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onTap(int pX, int pY) {
}
```

I hope this could help to people with the same issue ;)